# How can I stop CKEditor replacing paragraphs with double <br> when pasting from Word

Tags: parsing, ckeditor, wysiwyg, copy-paste

When I use the **Paste from Word** or **Paste as plain text** options in **CKEditor** double line returns get converted into double instances of <br>.

Whilst this is technically exactly what exists in the source file it would be fantastic if there were a way to have all double line returns be converted into paragraph tags when pasting from an external document. TinyMCE doesn’t seem to struggle with this.

Is this possible with CKEditor?

I'm using Pixel & Tonic's **Wygwam** version of CKEditor and the inference of [this support thread](http://help.pixelandtonic.com/brandonkelly/topics/paste_from_an_outside_text_editor_improperly_adds_s_instead_of_tags) is that it can't be done as exists :(

Answer (score 4):

Since I spent hours searching for the same thing and found lots of posts asking but none answering I decided to work it out on my own.

Here is the solution, hope it saves you the time I wasted:

In config.js add:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
    ev.editor.on('paste', function (ev) {
        ev.data.html = ev.data.html.replace(/<br>\s*<br>/g, '</p><p>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What really really fixed this issue for me was:

1. Put this line in config.js:
   "config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;"

This will create a "br" instead of a "p" when you hit ENTER in the ckeditor.

2. Then put this script where you replace the

   CKEDITOR.replace( 'descripcion', {  enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR, shiftEnterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR } );

   ```
                   CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev )
                   {
                    ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'br',
                    {
                     indent : false,
                     breakBeforeOpen : false,
                     breakAfterOpen : false,
                     breakBeforeClose : false,
                     breakAfterClose : false
                   });
                   });
                </script>
   ```

That script prevented the double "br"

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my work-around for this in CKEditor 4 (where `ck` is an editor instance):

```
        ck.on('afterPaste', function() {
            var data = ck.getData();
            data = data.replace(/<br \/>\s*<br \/>/g, '</p><p>');
            ck.setData(data);
        });
```